# postgresql how to select from columns by their position not names

Tags: postgresql

I can find valid Postgresql syntax to do this:

```
SELECT this, that, other FROM mytable ORDER BY 3, 2, 1;   // order by column position
```

...but cannot find any syntax to select the columns themselves by position:

```
SELECT 1, 2, 3 FROM mytable ORDER BY 3, 2, 1;    // valid, but wrong result :-(
SELECT COLUMN_VALUE( 1 ), COLUMN_VALUE( 2 ), COLUMN_VALUE( 3 ) FROM mytable;   // invalid :-(
```

I'm not interested in the `ORDER BY` except to use it to demonstrate that syntax exists that refers to columns by position in at least one context.

Before you say "why wouldn't you just refer to the columns by name?", suppose you have a large table of various data measures (length, width, weight, color, several FFT coefficients for shape, and dozens more...) and you want to compute covariance matrices or something similarly complex on this data. Suppose not all the data is relevant all the time, so you want to be able to select which data you use. So you're not writing the query; you're writing the code that generates the query. In that case (my case) it would be VERY handy to be able to access the data by column number and not by column name - it would simplify query generation.

That is, being able to `SELECT COLUMN_VALUE( 1 ) AS x1, COLUMN_VALUE( 2 ) AS x2, ...` makes life a lot easier once you start writing `( x - x1 )*( x - x2 )` or similar. And sure: I could write `SELECT this AS x1, that AS x2`, but to put that into code to generate the query requires the equivalent of `COLUMN_VALUE( COLUMN_NAME_LOOKUP( n ) )` when all I really want is `COLUMN_VALUE( n )`. That's pretty obviously more direct.

Is this possible somehow using straightforward syntax equivalent to `COLUMN_VALUE(n)`? Is it possible some other way?

I reject the argument that this is (allegedly) a potentially "dangerous" or "stupid" thing to do. Very clearly there is syntax for the `INSERT` command that does not list all the column names. This syntax therefore relies on (unchanged) column position, and suffers if column position changes. On that basis it seems perfectly reasonable for `SELECT` to provide position-based access to columns, and to also suffer if column position changes - I fully understand both risks and benefits. I just want to know if it is possible directly in Postgresql.

Comment: [`information_schema.attributes`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/infoschema-attributes.html) and [`pg_catalog.pg_attribute`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-attribute.html) have an order. Still, this sounds like a bad idea, you should rather use names to identify the column in your application. And in the `SELECT` clause of the query itself, you always *have to* use names.

Comment: "*`ORDER BY` demonstrate[s] that syntax exists that refers to columns by position in at least one context*" - actually that does not refer to the columns of the table, it refers to the columns in the selection result that the particular query makes. As such, it is available *only* in that context.

Comment: "*there is syntax for the `INSERT` command that does not list all the column names*" - yes, and using that form is considered dangerous and not recommended for exactly the reason that it breaks from schema changes.

Comment: No, it's not possible.